# How to debug multiple processes running in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, tmux

I'm running a multi-process application instance in a Docker container, each process running as a simple daemon. It is currently impossible for me to debug any runtime errors that arise in the container, because `docker attach` frequently hangs (and produces interleaved print statements), and neither `tmux` nor `screen` seem to function properly in the container. Moreover, redirecting stdout of each individual process to a log file like so:

```
python myfile.py 1>> mylogfile 2>&1 &
```

simply doesn't work, in that I only see warnings in the logfile. An ideal solution would be getting `tmux` to work. How do you debug processes in your container?

Comment: In general, don't try to run many processes in a single container. For debugging, you should be able to get a shell inside your container, using `docker exec -it <yourcontainer> bash` (or `sh`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't run multiple processes in one container

For all the reasons you outlined.

### Use supervisord

In the earlier days of Docker "don't run multiple processes!" wasn't such a big rule. Supervisord was the recommended initd-like tool for handling multiple services in one container. It can try to monitor both and it can handle the logging properly.

### Use `docker exec` to debug

`docker exec [-it] <container> <command>` lets you run an extra command on a running container. Use it to get a shell and explore.